# Regex taking equal sign when I don't think it's supposed to in c++

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, c++11

So I'm supposed to take in user input and evaluate if user input is a valid infix expression. I only accept `+ - / * ( )` and digits.
So the easiest way would be to use regex.

This is my regex expression:`[\(\)\d\+\-\/\*]+`.
I've also tried: `[\(\)0-9\+\-\/\*]+` as well as 
`[\(\)[:digit:]\+\-\/\*]+`

I've also tried without escape characters and yet I'm still getting the same result.

The issue is that when I put `=` as the expression, it passes.

Code below:

```
cout<<"Enter the infix expression: ";
cin>>userInput;
regex infix ("[\(\)\d\+\-\/\*]+");
while(cin.fail()||regex_match(userInput,infix)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cout<<"Error: Not a valid infix expression!\n";
    cout<<"Enter the infix expression: ";
    cin>>userInput;
}
cout<<"Valid expression!\n";
```

Current output:

```
Enter the infix expression: =
Valid expression!
```

Expected output:

```
Enter the infix expression: =
Error: Not a valid infix expression!
```

Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: I've never done regex in c++, but in other languages you don't need to escape most characters when you use square braces, but the `-` needs to be put at the end. I'd try `"[()+/*\d-]"`

Comment: I think the backslash character itself must be escaped, mustn't it? `"[()+/*\\d-]"`

Comment: You realize the Regex will never validate the infix expression?

Comment: @NetMage You mean I should use `!` instead? I tried that too but then it doesn't take valid expressions such as `3*4`

Comment: I bet you need `regex infix("[()\\d+/*-]+");`. Note [it does not match a `=`.](https://ideone.com/6vmW4c)

Comment: I mean that even if you handled the escapes properly, it is very difficult to impossible to reject invalid expressions such as `(((2+3` or `+-*123`.

Comment: @NetMage oh, I understand. That is another method I need to write. Currently, I am trying to prevent any entries of invalid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed regex declaration will look like

```
regex infix(R"([()\d+/*-]+)");
```

or, if you cannot use raw string literals:

```
regex infix("[()\\d+/*-]+");
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/6vmW4c).

Note that a hyphen in between `+` and `/`, and regardless of escaping, creates a *range* between those 2 symbols. Also, `\d` must look like `\\d` in a regular string literal and as `\d` in a raw string literal.

The `/` symbol does not have to be escaped.

Also, the logic must be adjusted to return appropriate error messages/behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string userInput = "=";
    regex infix(R"([()\d+/*-]+)");
    if(regex_match(userInput,infix)){
        cout<<"Valid expression!\n";
    } else {
        cout<<"Error: Not a valid infix expression!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
// => Error: Not a valid infix expression!
```

Comment: ahhh, I see. Thanks

Comment: Well, I also think there was a problem with the code logic.

Comment: yeah, I had to tweak the while condition. Thanks.

Comment: this isn't work for 4++ and returns valid.

Comment: @etel876 The current solution is tailored for the problem explained in the original post. `4++` matches as per regex requirements. If you have a different set of requirements, you cannot use the regex solution from the current answer. Please check if there are no other SO threads that could help you and then consider posting your question.